# How set date into list view edittext from daepickerdialod?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, datepickerdialog

I have try lots code and solution but not get the result.
My requirement is when i click on listview edittext then open a datepicker dialog and set date into listview edittext.

get the date from datepicker dialog but when i set into listview edittext then edittext not set any value.

so how can i set date in listview edittext.

if any one know that then help me out.

code:-

```
productDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
        {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
            {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                Log.v("Date", "date " + dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                updateDate(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }}, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

holder.edt_Three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                productDatePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

private void updateDate(String dDate) {
        Log.v("Date", "date " + dDate);
        //TODO
        holder.edt_Three.setText(dDate);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show any snippet you are using ?

Comment: same thing i have implement in list view edittext then not working

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/datepicker-and-timepicker-dialog-in.html

Comment: Please post the code that you are using .

Comment: May be issue is with edit text change it with textView

Comment: are you getting any error?show where you opening your dailg

Comment: did all this code is in getView()...?

Comment: not getting any error and open dialo on edittext onclick

Comment: yes all code in getview()